# NETCONF get running configuration

Tags: netconf, ncclient

I am trying to get a running configuration from a network device, using **NETCONF** (not one of the well known such as Cisco/Juniper, etc).

Using **ncclient**, I successfully get the capabilities and schemas but when trying to get running config the SSH session is suddenly closed.

Is there any way to send a XML file to the server instead of using the get_config() method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send RPC's direclty with `manager.rpc()`

https://github.com/ncclient/ncclient/blob/968b09010131143a3ed3ed1fa9da52d57c167c20/ncclient/manager.py#L50